# Neo4j/Cypher: Setting a map and property yields "expected valid query body"

Tags: neo4j, cypher

The following query fails:

```
MATCH n:User
WHERE n.email = "test"
SET n = {data}, n.created = timestamp()
RETURN n
```

Is this expected?  Is it a bug?  Is there a workaround?  Do I have to compute the timestamp and send it along with `{data}`?

Comment: Which neo4j version are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A slight modification of your statement using 2 `SET` clauses works:

```
MATCH n:User
WHERE n.email = "test"
SET n = {data} 
SET n.created = timestamp()
RETURN n
```

Comment: I did not know you could have two sets!  Interesting, thank you :)